# FPS App crashes when compiling, "Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In the 2D fps I'm making, I am making a 2D maze for the avatar to navigate in. I just finished coding it however whenever I compile it the app instantly crashes.

The error that makes it crash is the following
"Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound"

and occurs in this file

Bitmap.swift

```
import UIKit

public struct Bitmap
{
    public private(set) var pixels: [Color]
    public let width: Int
    
    public init(width: Int, pixels: [Color], height: Int)
    {
        self.width = width
        self.pixels = pixels
    }
}


public extension Bitmap
{
    var height: Int
    {
        let bitmapheight = pixels.count / width
        return bitmapheight
    }
    subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Color
    {
        get { return pixels[y * width + x] }
        set {
            guard x >= 0, y >= 0, x < width, y < height else {
                return
            }
            pixels[y * width + x] = newValue}
            }
    
    init(width: Int, height: Int, color: Color) {
        self.pixels = Array(repeating: color, count: width * height)
        self.width = width
}
    mutating func fill(rect: Rect, color: Color)
    {
        for y in Int(rect.min.y) ..< Int(rect.max.y)
        {
            for x in Int(rect.min.x) ..< Int(rect.max.x)
            {
                self[x, y] = color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

at the line

```
for x in Int(rect.min.x) ..< Int(rect.max.x)
```

Since it's a big project and there's multiple files calling from one another in both the main game files and the game engine files, you can find the rest of the source code in the link below:

https://github.com/KingDecorpel12/RampageFPS

Game Engine files, including Bitmap.swift, will be in Rampage/Source/Engine while the main game files will be in Rampage/Source/Rampage.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part is -

```
Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound
```

You need to make sure that it always holds true.

```
Int(rect.min.x) ..< Int(rect.max.x)
```

Seems like your input causes `Int(rect.min.x)` to produce  a value that is bigger than `Int(rect.max.x)`.

Comment: Yes but I don't know why since in the line above it I typed the same thing just for y instead of x and it builds fine.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line, check the values of `rect.max.x` &`rect.min.x`. See where the wrong value is coming from and fix the value.

Comment: I put a breakpoint but I don't see a way to check the values of ```rect.max.x``` and ```rect.min.x```. The error also seems to show up in the lines ``` bitmap.fill(rect: rect, color: .white)``` in Renderer.swift and ```        renderer.draw(world)``` in ViewController.swift.

Comment: You can check out this article for how to start debugging, put breakpoints, check values in Xcode. https://learnappmaking.com/debugging-with-xcode-ios-how-to/

Comment: Update: So after running the code with a breakpoint I found the following values:


min Engine.Vector 
x = (Double) 51.75
y = (Double) 0
max Engine.Vector 
x = (Double) 2
y = (Double) 51.75

This is for ```rect.min.x``` and ```rect.max.x``` . Still haven't found a fix for it yet

Comment: Then the issue is clear. `rect.min.x = 51.75` & `rect.max.x = 2`. First one can't be bigger than second one. You need to pass correct input values for it to work.

Comment: Not sure how much help this is, bur when I run the code, the following shows up in the terminal.

Engine was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.


This is so weird considering ```rect.min.y``` and ```rect.max.y``` works fine